# Python: mathematical operation of Combination on list of numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7

let's say I have a list of numbers:

```
my_list = range(0,1001,50)
```

I want to make every single possible combination of threes (threes = [a,b,c]) based on **my_list**, for example: [0,50,100], [0,50,150], ..., [0,50,1000], [0,100,150], ...

Threes don't have to be stored in a list, it's just an example of data structure.

And after that I want to put every single threes' values (a,b,c) to some sort of formula.

How could I make that? I'm kinda beginner in Python and haven't experienced with more complicated mathematical structures yet. Or is it possible to do on some kind of loop...?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You had the correct term (`combination`). Finding the correct method wouldn't have been too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) :

```
my_list = range(0,1000,50)
from itertools import combinations
combinations(my_list,3)
```

From the doc :

> combinations() p, r  r-length tuples, in sorted order, no repeated
>   elements

It creates an iterable. Converted to a list, it looks like :

```
[(0, 50, 100), (0, 50, 150), (0, 50, 200), (0, 50, 250), (0, 50, 300), ...
```

Comment: thank you, I don't know why Google didn't show me this library first...

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the wonderful `itertools` module, that has `combinations()` in it:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations(range(10), 3))
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 4), (0, 1, 5), (0, 1, 6), (0, 1, 7), (0, 1, 8), (0
, 1, 9), (0, 2, 3), (0, 2, 4), (0, 2, 5), (0, 2, 6), (0, 2, 7), (0, 2, 8), (0, 2
, 9), (0, 3, 4), (0, 3, 5), (0, 3, 6), (0, 3, 7), (0, 3, 8), (0, 3, 9), (0, 4, 5
), (0, 4, 6), (0, 4, 7), (0, 4, 8), (0, 4, 9), (0, 5, 6), (0, 5, 7), (0, 5, 8),
(0, 5, 9), (0, 6, 7), (0, 6, 8), (0, 6, 9), (0, 7, 8), (0, 7, 9), (0, 8, 9), (1,
 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 6), (1, 2, 7), (1, 2, 8), (1, 2, 9), (1, 3,
 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 3, 7), (1, 3, 8), (1, 3, 9), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6)
, (1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (1, 4, 9), (1, 5, 6), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (1, 5, 9), (
1, 6, 7), (1, 6, 8), (1, 6, 9), (1, 7, 8), (1, 7, 9), (1, 8, 9), (2, 3, 4), (2,
3, 5), (2, 3, 6), (2, 3, 7), (2, 3, 8), (2, 3, 9), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6), (2, 4,
7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 4, 9), (2, 5, 6), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 8), (2, 5, 9), (2, 6, 7),
 (2, 6, 8), (2, 6, 9), (2, 7, 8), (2, 7, 9), (2, 8, 9), (3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 6), (3
, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (3, 4, 9), (3, 5, 6), (3, 5, 7), (3, 5, 8), (3, 5, 9), (3, 6
, 7), (3, 6, 8), (3, 6, 9), (3, 7, 8), (3, 7, 9), (3, 8, 9), (4, 5, 6), (4, 5, 7
), (4, 5, 8), (4, 5, 9), (4, 6, 7), (4, 6, 8), (4, 6, 9), (4, 7, 8), (4, 7, 9),
(4, 8, 9), (5, 6, 7), (5, 6, 8), (5, 6, 9), (5, 7, 8), (5, 7, 9), (5, 8, 9), (6,
 7, 8), (6, 7, 9), (6, 8, 9), (7, 8, 9)]
```

Then you can feed that to your function:

```
def f(a,b,c):
   return a * b * c

print [f(*x) for x in itertools.combinations(range(10), 3)]
```